# How to include one CoffeeScript file in another in order to share specs amongst jasmine

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I'm unable to get CoffeeScript in Jasmine to include another file. I'd like to share common functions amongst Jasmine specs which are written in CoffeeScript.

I'm sure I'm getting the syntax wrong, I've tried `require` and `include`, I've tried putting the file in the same folder just to be sure, I've tried `# =` syntax too.

I'm looking for something similar to include in php, i.e. `go here -> compile this -> come back` so the `compile this` step can easily be shared.

NB, I am *not* talking about inclusion in the compiled source, but inclusion before / during the compile step - I am also running these scripts as part of a Jasmine / Evergreen setup, accessing the URL in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a *build system*, which Coffeescript is not. Coffeescript can translate the *syntax* of a single file only into plain Javascript, it does not concern itself with concatenating or bundling additional external resources. There are a metric ton of Javascript build systems which can inline `require` calls; personally I'm very happy with [Duo](http://duojs.org) at the moment, but [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) is the de facto kitchen sink in Javascript build systems, so have a look at both and others.