# What is the equivalent of this Sass structure in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have this in Sass:

```
@import 'shared/file1';
@import 'shared/file2';
@import 'shared/file3';
```

The result is that in the compiled file the contents of files 1 - 3 are output in sequence. Sass goes to the files in order, compiles what it finds, and outputs the result.

What is the exact equivalent in CoffeeScript?

Comment: Besides the fact that sass and coffeescript are unrelated, there's no import mechanism in coffeescript.

Comment: @Antoine languages can be completely unrelated and share basic common features ... machine code and javascript are not really related, but they share conditionals, for example

Comment: I think for this you need other tools like requireJS or other javascript tools. Pretty much all javascript tools will works with coffescript

Comment: Not sure of your use, but you can use ```require``` to load local or published packages as well as other types of data. E.g. ```template = require './layouts/ItemView.jade'``` or ```myData = require '../../public/data/myData.json'```. Try it out in the interactive interpreter and see if this will work for you. If able to use require,  you can have one file that 'imports' many other .coffee files.

Comment: @ToniLeigh You were asking for an _exact equivalent_ for `@import` in coffeescript. `@import` is a sass language feature, and neither javascript nor coffeescript have anything like that, adding to the fact mentioned by previous commenters that apart from being _lanuage preprocessors_, they are completely unrelated. The only thing coming close to that is **RequireJS**, which is an external library.

Comment: another important similarity is that they are likely to sit together in the skill-set, so a user who can answer can hopefully understand the example I'm presenting - sass was the clearest way to show an example that I can think  of

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include one CoffeeScript file in another in order to share specs amongst jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518302/how-to-include-one-coffeescript-file-in-another-in-order-to-share-specs-amongst)

Comment: @deceze that's my question lol, I actually think this one is clearer though, the other should be removed

Comment: @ToniLeigh I think most here do actually understand your proposition, and you are right in saying that it's very likely to find sass and coffeescript in the same project. However, the answer to your question will still be no IMO.

Comment: @Toni Indeed, that's you. Wasn't that answer enough? However many times you keep asking this question and however many different things you compare it to: **Coffeescript simply cannot do it.**

Comment: no it wasn't enough, hence I simplified the question and more specific (tbh, I forgot about asking that question, I probably saw it suggested but thought it didn't answer exactly what I was asking), but an answer of 'no this isn't possible' is perfectly acceptable